# how to import metamask pop-up in my solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs

I am learning solidity and developing a contract. The contract will have the external blockchain wallet address of users (mapped with their username) and this wallet will store NFTs uploaded on my contract.
for example, i create my account in the contract and then minted an NFT. Now, this NFT is stored in my wallet.
so, my question is - How to make a contract that would allow the user to connect their external wallet to my contract, mint an NFT and store it in their wallet?

Answer (score 0):

That's not something that is handled by the smart contract in itself. Your smart contract would be connected to a dApp (a website, which serves as a graphical UI for the smart contract) and the dApp would be the one handling the connection, using libraries such as ethers.js or  web3.js, look them up.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with **remix** **ide** you have to choose your environment (metamask wallet) and you can test it as you like in **testnet** **networks**.
but if you are working on a **dapp** you can connect & use it there many frameworks(**Hardhat**) and libraries(**web3.js**, **ethers.js** ...)